# Run python public server with sockets from Raspberry Pi access point

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, access-point

I have a router that makes it extremely difficult to run port-forwarding through it. Plus, I would rather be able to just pretty much plug my Pi in and have my server running. Setting up a Raspberry Pi as a wireless access point is pretty easy and straight forward. I would like to have a python server, which runs on the same Raspberry Pi, that allows me to run a public server off of the access point. So basically instead of having to use port forwarding with my router, the server made with sockets in python uses the access point to be public. is this something that sounds possible?

*update* This is NOT for local use, I want it to be a server that I could connect to states away

Comment: It's for local use only ?

Comment: Is your rooter UPnP enabled. Check for set NAT with 'miniupnp' package.